# What's the best way to keep access to the ApplicationUserManager after the controller has been disposed?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-identity-2

Ran into an interesting problem yesterday. Only my mvc website with Identity 1 I used an `IPrincipal` extension method to do custom authentication, which worked fine across all the razor views where it was needed. Now with Identity 2, I need to get access in the extension method to the `ApplicationUserManager`, so I've been forced to pass the `HttpContext.Current` through from all the views.

This works fine, apart from inside razor `@section` sections - following the call stack, it appears that these don't get rendered until after the controller has been disposed, which disposes my database and user managers etc.

What would be the best way around this limitation? I want to keep using sections, as they let me easily inject javascript down the very bottom of the html, but I also want to keep using razor extensions inside these sections as they are a very nice, easy way to control what gets outputted to the page.

At the moment I'm being forced to create a new `ApplicationUserManager` and `MyDbContext`, stuff them in the `ViewBag` and then pass them along to the extension, which isn't ideal.

Example of my extension method:

```
public static bool HasPermission(this IPrincipal source, ApplicationUserManager um, MyDbContext db, string controller, string method) {
        if (!source.Identity.IsAuthenticated) {
            return false;
        }

        var roles = um.GetRoles(source.Identity.GetUserId());
        if (roles.Count == 0) {
            return false;
        }

        // Admins have global access
        string role = roles[0];
        if (role.Equals("Admin")) {
            return true;
        }
        // This is fine being un-domained, permissions are global
        PermissionMatrix permission = db.PermissionMatrices.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Controller == controller && x.Action == method && x.RoleName == role);
        return permission != null;
    }
```

Example of where it's used:

```
@if (User.HasPermission((ApplicationUserManager)ViewBag.UserManager, (MyDbContext)ViewBag.Database, "Event", "Create")) {
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
}
```

Editing to make the problem itself more clear:

This was the extension method before I put my hack in -

```
public static bool HasPermission(this IPrincipal source, HttpContext context, string controller, string method) {
    var userManager = context.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationUserManager>();
    var myDb = context.GetOwinContext().Get<MyDbContext>();
```

Like I kind of said above, this works (passing the HttpContext.Current through from a .cshtml page), UNLESS the call is inside a razor `@section`, then it fails, because these run AFTER the controller has been disposed, which disposes the stuff inside the OwinContext.

The code above is the hacky way I've got it working at the moment; in my Controllers I have to create an extra MyDbContext and an extra ApplicationUserManager.

Comment: Side note: official approach would be to remove that logic from the view and move it to controller. (obviously not an answer).

Comment: The question is why you parameterized ApplicationUserManager and MyDbContext ????

Comment: Because, if I send through the HttpContext.Current to the extension method; and then call the extension method inside a razor section, all of the objects you want to get out of the OwinContext have been disposed. ApplicationUserManager, MyDbContext etc. 

Note this approach works fine for calls running in the normal razor page, just not inside sections.